# Command to check performance of command

Tags: discord.py

I have a command to check the performance of another command which returns info like how long the command took to run and if an error occured within it. But this only works with commands, that don't have a permission limit like having administrator perms.

How can I fix this so that I can bypass the permissions limit of the command that will be checked the performance of?
The code that I currently have is:

````py
@commands.command(hidden=True)
@is_owner()
async def perf(self, ctx, *, command):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        """Checks the timing of a command, attempting to suppress HTTP and DB calls."""

        msg = copy.copy(ctx.message)
        msg.content = ctx.prefix + command

        new_ctx = await self.bot.get_context(msg, cls=type(ctx))
        new_ctx._db = PerformanceMocker()

        # Intercepts the Messageable interface a bit
        new_ctx._state = PerformanceMocker()
        new_ctx.channel = PerformanceMocker()
        new_ctx.author = ctx.author

        if new_ctx.command is None:
                return await ctx.send('No command found')
                    

        print(new_ctx.content)
        print(new_ctx.author.permissions)

        start = time.perf_counter()
        try:
                await new_ctx.command.invoke(new_ctx)
        except commands.CommandError:
                end = time.perf_counter()
                success = False
                try:
                        await ctx.send(f'```py\n{traceback.format_exc()}\n```')
                except discord.HTTPException:
                        pass
        else:
                end = time.perf_counter()
                success = True

        await ctx.send(f'Status: {success} Time: {(end - start) * 1000:.2f}ms')
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking out [jishaku](https://pypi.org/project/jishaku/), which has a builtin debug command that will output any errors and the total time taken.

To answer your question directly, you should take a look at [commands.Command.__call__](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command.__call__) which will bypass all checks, converters, and cooldowns.